# parse XDocument for attributes

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

I have tried to parse an XML file like this:

```
<books>
   <book>
      <attr name="Moby Dick">Moby Dick is a classic</attr>
      <attr isbn="isbnNumber">123456789</attr>
   </book>
</books>
```

How can I get the value of "123456789"?  I don't really need the first attribute.

I tried reading these in a foreach loop getting XElements but I keep getting a NULL object exception.

```
foreach(XElement xe in XDoc.Attribute("attr"))
{
   string str = xe.Attribute("isbnNumber").Value   // NULL EXCEPTION HERE
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: A weird xml... why do you make these attributes child nodes of `Book` instead of `<book name="bla" ISBN="bla"...`

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the `XPathSelectElement()` extension method [you'll need to use System.Xml.XPath to get them].

E.g.

```
var isbn = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//book/attr[@isbn='isbnNumber']").Value
```

PS. A good XPath tester is at: http://www.yetanotherchris.me/home/2010/6/7/online-xpath-tester.html

Comment: Personally, I agree that XPath is probably the better solution here. I never was particularly impressed with the LINQ to XML way.

Comment: Me too... XPath makes deep queries infinitely more readable but they also represent another syntax for a maintaining developer to come to grips with (particularly if doing complex stuff). Though in this example, it's much cleaner and just as easy to understand in my opinion!

Answer (score 1):

123456789 is actually the value of an element, not an attribute. What you want can be done like so:

```
XElement attr = xDoc.Descendants("attr")
                    .FirstOrDefault( x=> 
                        (string)x.Attribute("isbn") == "isbnNumber"
                    );

string isbn = (string)attr;
```

You could even make it one line but this might be easier to read if you're new to LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't figure out how to respond to the individual answers..... but I implemented them both and they both work.

I am going with Reddog's answer as it is a little more straightforward and being new to LINQ it is the easiest as of now for readability.

Thanks for the responses!